# Isolate DIV from outer HTML

Tags: html

I need to "isolate/separate" a `<div>` from the html around it. Meaning, the `<p>More text</p>` underneath the `<div>` should be connected to the `<h1>` and the first paragraph but NOT the `<h2>` and the paragraph inside the information panel. Is that possible?

```
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div> //this div should be isolated in a machine reading perspective from the HTML around it
      <h2>Information</h2>
      <p>Some information text</p>
    </div>
    <p>More text that follows the paragraph above the div, NOT the div itself.</p>
```

Edit. It has to do with Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG). The HTML itself works just fine but I got a review from some WCAG instance telling me this is not machine readable in a correct way. The text that follows the information div should be the continuation of the text above the information div, not the text in the div itself.

They say this would be correct:

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<div>
  <h2>Information</h2>
  <p>Some information text</p>
</div>
<h2><Header</h2>
<p>More text</p>
```

Or this:

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>More text</p>
<div>
   <h2>Information</h2>
   <p>Some information text</p>
</div>
```

Problem is this is about a cms and the editors wants to be able to add information panels in the middle of a paragraph without the need of a new header underneath it. That's why I'm asking. Mission impossible?

Comment: What do you mean by "connected"? Can you show us an example of what it looks like now vs what you want to achieve?

Comment: "Connected" is probably a bad word, it has to do with Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG). The HTML itself works just fine but I got a review from some WCAG instance telling me this is not machine readable in a correct way. The text that follows the information div is the continuation of the text above the information div, not the text in the div itself. Fluffy huh? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Some information text<p>
```

Should be

```
<p>Some information text</p>
```

Comment: Yes, it is better. But this does not make a difference in the result!

Comment: Sorry, but that was just a typo. The HTML itself works, but I got some complaints about Web Content Accessibility Guidelines. Hardly don't understand it myself, but somehow I need to connect the text above the div and the text underneath in a "machine reading" way...?

Answer (score -1):

You can this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<style>
h1{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
}

p {
    color: red;
    font-size:15px;
}

div.more-area{
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.more-area > h2 {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}

div.more-area > p {
    color: pink;
    font-size: 12px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>More text</p>
<div class="more-area">
   <h2>Information</h2>
   <p>Some information text</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't post comments as an answer please

Comment: I have edit my initial post with more info.

Comment: Thanks, but not valid, css is just a stylish thing... I need a proper way telling this information div isn't in any way connected to the html around it. I think ARIA is what Im looking for, though don't now how to use it. And it has to be tagged in the information div, not outside (because of technical restraints).